# Word for moving a program into a production environment

Tags: single-word-requests, software, computing

I work as a software developer, and after we finishing developing a program, we have to move it from the development environment into the production environment so that we can test it under real-world condition and the client can start to use it.

I was wondering what the best word would be to describe the process?

- My boss is fond of "productionize", which i'm not sure is actually a word
- I sometimes use "deploy/deployment"

I was wondering if there were other suggestions?

Comment: It goes into "beta," as I recall.  A beta version is being tested (probably among a limited set of users or on a limited number of machines) and bugs are to be expected.

Comment: @Xanne Yes, the Beta test phase is the stage immediately after development, where a lot of testing has to go on (it could be called Alpha testing, but I've never heard that term used). As you say a more or less restricted set of customers agree to act as guinea pigs, run the Beta software in their business environment and feed back problems they find. The fully tested version is then Released (a term presumably derived from the music industry). If there is no Beta phase  you go straight to release.'Productionize' is unnecessary and just plain horrible!

Comment: @BoldBen - I'm in general agreement. Alpha testing is in-house testing. Beta testing is selected customers using it. But anytime software is given to someone it is "released", so you can have an "alpha release" (or in other words you can "release the alpha version to the testing department"), a "beta release" or I guess the "normal" one would be a "general release".

Comment: [If anyone would like to write BoldBen and my comments into an answer, with some research to actually back them up, please ping me so I can upvote and delete my comments.]

Comment: Some people call it "release", but I've always found "escape" to be more accurate.

Comment: @HotLicks So true, some of it even seems to have oozed out by osmosis!

Comment: The problem I see with 'productionize' is not that it isn't a word, but that it implies actually doing something to make it 'production-ready' when you're asking for the act of moving itself from development to production.

As a software developer too, I would agree with the others that 'release' is the most appropriate word here, but specifically you're doing a 'release to production.' Doing a 'beta-release' is even more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/productize

> **PRODUCTIZE**
>
> To make something into a commercial product.

I often see it used in the software industry.

It implies additional development, *e.g.* compatibility testing, debugging, documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Publish. The software is now visible to the users, just as a galley becomes visible to the users once the printed copies hit the market.

Answer (score 0):

Productionize - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/productionize

Productionalize - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/productionalize

The former is about fitness for the production environment. The latter is about your service|system|etc.'s ability to consume other production services. That's my read anyway.

Deploying is the act of building your code|project and moving the target artifact into an environment where it can start providing service. So simply saying you're "deploying" doesn't carry the same cost or render the same result as "putting your service in production"... Like, for example, you may deploy to a beta stage (or some other pre-prod development stage), you may promote your service to a gamma stage, you may test your service in data via automation and other integration testing methods. You may then finally promote your service to the production stage.

At that point, you've "productionalized" your service. During beta/gamma, you've "productionized" your service by ensuring the highest likelihood (via said testing and testing and testing) that your service can consume up/downstream dependencies sufficiently.

Pedantic, but pithy.

Answer (score -2):

You may use **migrate**. This, of course includes only the sense of "moving" not "testing".

> **migrate**: [transitive + from/to] to move information or software from
>   one computer system to another

Please check [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/migrate)

Comment: -1 It's not about moving software, it's about the software going into  another phase.